# Icon for Primefaces Dynamic Menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to get an icon from JSF resources folder to a dynamic menu created from org.primefaces.model.MenuModel; The setIcon methods of menu take only a string as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the setIcon method takes a string which is the name of the icon you want to set. So for example:

```
    MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem();
    item3.setIcon("ui-icon-print");
```

Are you perhaps trying to use an image instead of an icon? There is a cheat sheet of predefined icons here: http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/

If you are trying to create your own icon then you will need to do what @Ravi has indicated and create a custom CSS class which you will reference in the setIcon() method.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a custom icon by using css style class like this:

```
<p:menuitem icon="barca" ... />
```

and load the image located at resources/default/images/icons folder like this:

```
.barca {
    background: url('#{resource['default:images/icons/barca_logo.png']}') no-repeat;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```

Comment: I create the menu dynamically.                                     In the JSF page, I use only                                  <pou:menubar  model="#{menu.model}" />.                             In the back bean I create menu like 
        MenuItem item; 
        item = new MenuItem();
        item.setValue(getLabel("home"));
        item.setUrl("index.xhtml");
        model.addMenuItem(item);                                         So your method can not be applied in this context.