# Primefaces - MenuItem icon not showing

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to add custom icons to the primefaces tiered side menu, by the method suggested here: [Icon for Primefaces Dynamic Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045942/icon-for-primefaces-dynamic-menu)

However, I am having a simliar problem to this: 
[Primefaces dynamic menu icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695332/primefaces-dynamic-menu-icon-not-showing)

The icon is not visible, and by inspecting the element, I only see the default icons in the code.
Here is my Java code:

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setIcon("icon-disk");
```

The CSS:

```
.icon-disk{
    background-image: url(../resources/images/icon_indicatorlist.png);  
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```

The xhtml:

```
<p:panelMenu model="#{menuBean.getModel(menus.id)}" type="tiered" />
```

On inspecting element, this is what I see:

```
<h3 class="ui-panelmenu-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
    <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Item1</a>
</h3>
```

What do I need to edit or add? I am using PF 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setIcon("ui-icon-disk");
```

Comment: I want to add a custom icon. Created by my own image file.

Comment: to add icon you can use code like this `<p:graphicImage value="/icon/edit.png" />`

Comment: I want to add it through Java code. Since all menu items have a unique icon associated with them. The xhtml side does not know the item name or icon or anything. The whole menu is generated dynamically, by his function call: model="#{menuBean.getModel(menus.id)}"

Answer (score 0):

i guess your problem is the path to your images and not PF-Problem.

depending on the Structure of your Project, try to change any background-image of any test HTML-Element, just to see if your path to your images is correct.

an example:

```
+ Java-SRC
+ WebContents [folder]
    + resources[folder]
        + css [folder]
          styles.css
             .anyClass{
                 background: transparent url('images/any.png') !important;
             }
        + images [folder]
             any.png
             xyz.jpg
             ....
    + Views [folder]
        index.xhtml
             ...
             <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
             ...
        signin.xhtml
        ....
```

Comment: The path is correct. I am using images in other places as well, it all works fine.